# If an api returns an error try api again for few times in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I wanted to do something like if any of my api returns an error then it will try again for lets say 3 times and if still 4th time it gives an error then show error to user.

I'm try interceptor so that it works for all api :

```
interceptor.responseError = function(rejection) {
  if (rejection.status === 404) {
    console.log('404 error');
  }
```

It will console every time I get 404 error but I don't know how I can call that service again in this condition.

Please let me know if there's anything available in AngularJS

Comment: Just curious, in which use case do you want to retry after a 404?

Comment: Actually 404 is just an example status code is different

Answer (score 2):

You can use Observables and use the Retry function available. Hope this is helpful :

https://medium.com/javascript-everyday/rxjs-retrywhen-operator-15e3c83b97eb